# gxt: custom grid cell style

Tags: java, grid, cell, render, gxt

I want to create custom cell in grid. This is not a problem. 
The problem: text in this custom cell has incorrect style.

```
myColumn.setRenderer(new GridCellRenderer<TaskModel>() {
        public Object render(TaskModel model, String property, ColumnData config, int rowIndex, int colIndex, ListStore<TaskModel> taskModelListStore, Grid<TaskModel> taskModelGrid) {
            VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();

            Html html = new Html("xxxx");

            Button b = new Button("xxxxxxxx");

            panel.add(html);
            panel.add(b);

            return panel;
        }
    });
```

Why this happened?

[image: Style example]

Answer (score 0):

You must set style for your own.

```
 Html html = new Html("<div class=\"myStyle\">xxxx</div>");
```

then in stylesheet.css file (it may be named different depending on your project setup)

```
.myStyle {
    //style you want
}
```

or inline, if you don't want edit style file, for eg.:

```
 Html html = new Html("<div style=\"font-weight: bold;\">xxxx</div>");
```

However I prefer storing styles where its place is, outside the code (as in my first suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text styled the same way as other GXT text, create a [GXT Text](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxtdocs/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/Text.html) object and add that instead. If you want a custom style, then you'll need to use your own CSS as suggested by @denu.

I think something like `new Text("xxxx");` might be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

@Travis
What the difference:

```
ColumnConfig column1 = new ColumnConfig("1", 200);
        column1.setRenderer(new GridCellRenderer<TaskModel>() {
            public Object render(TaskModel model, String property, ColumnData config, int rowIndex, int colIndex, ListStore<TaskModel> taskModelListStore, Grid<TaskModel> taskModelGrid) {
                VerticalPanel panel1 = new VerticalPanel();

                panel1.add(new Html("html"));
                panel1.add(new Label("label"));
                panel1.add(new Text("text"));
                panel1.add(new Button("button"));
                return panel1;
            }
        });
        ColumnConfig column2 = new ColumnConfig("2", 200);
        column2.setRenderer(new GridCellRenderer<TaskModel>() {
            public Object render(TaskModel model, String property, ColumnData config, int rowIndex, int colIndex, ListStore<TaskModel> taskModelListStore, Grid<TaskModel> taskModelGrid) {
                return new Text("text");
            }
        });
```

[image]